# I can't save data in table in PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to add data manually to my table customers in PgAdmin and then I would like to click the save button and save them in the table.

The problem is that the save button is unclickable.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

I only manage to save these two rows by exiting this window and when the prompt says if I would like to save the data I click yes and it saves it but I would like to save them by clicking on the save button in this window.

How can I do that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct icon. The icon that the floppy image is for save file. The save data changes is the next one over that looks like a grid.

Comment: In the picture you attached there is no 'dirty' row. So the inactive save button is intentional. There is a binding on F6 with the save operation. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you didn't want to save them to a new file *Save File* (accesskey + S), but you wanted to save the changes you made on that file. What you want is to click *Save Data Changes* (F6) instead.